# jQuery addClass with animation

Tags: jquery

I have a progress bar with a webkit animation:

```
              -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite !important;
```

I'm looking to be able to start the animation by adding it in a class.

```
.doit {
              -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite !important;
}
```

This is the jQuery I'm trying to use:

```
$('#CurrentTierProgressOuterTop > span:after, .animate > span > span').addClass('doit');
```

The CSS:

```
#CurrentTierProgressOuterTop > span:after, .animate > span > span {

             background-image: 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, 
               color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
               color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), 
               color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
               color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
               color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent)
            );
         background-image: 
            -moz-linear-gradient(
              -45deg, 
               rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
               transparent 25%, 
               transparent 50%, 
               rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
               rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
               transparent 75%, 
               transparent
            );
         content: "";
         position: absolute;
         top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
         z-index: 1;

         -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
         -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
         -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
             -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
                    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
                 border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
             -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
          -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
                 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
              -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
                     border-top-left-radius: 20px;
                  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
         overflow: hidden;
}
```

Placing the webkit snippet within the above CSS triggers the animation perfectly.

The HTML:

```
<div id = "CurrentTierProgressOuterTop" style="display: none;">
<div id = "CurrentTierProgressInnerTop" style ="width:0px;height:10px;float:left;background-color:white;font-size:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have the HTML that you're aging this class to?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want: http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/

`switchClass` animates all class changes. It's part of jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use addClass() on a pseudo-element

> `$(#CurrentTierProgressOuterTop > span:after)`

and that won't work because the pseudo-elements aren't part of the DOM.
Try to change the targeted element.